# How do I remove (not hide) UI button in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, constraints, show-hide

I have a view with a lot of `UI buttons`. I want some of the buttons to show and some to be hidden depending on my dynamic content. This can be done with `button.isHidden = true`. The problem is that the layout still set its constraints to the hidden buttons which create a lot of empty space.[image]

You can see the empty space at the bottom in the picture where the buttons are hidden. So, is it possible to make the buttons "gone" instead of hidden? In `Android Studio` there is a `isGone` code (can't remember the exact code) that not only hides the button but removes the height and width of it as well.

Comment: With the layout you've shown, you could embed the buttons in a `UIStackView` ... when you set `.isHidden = true` on a button (view) that is in a stack view, that "space" is automatically removed and the remaining buttons will "slide up".

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out :)